# Append form to a result page in Javascript

Tags: javascript, append

I am pretty new to Javascript. I am trying to add a form element to my Javascript Quiz results page.

```
function viewResultPage() {
    console.log("viewResult Page: ", currentQuestionIndex, " ", timeleft);
    // inner html Sets or returns the content of an element
    welcometxt.innerHTML = ""
    var allDoneEl = document.createElement("span");
    allDoneEl.innerHTML = "Quiz is over and final score is: " + timeleft;
    welcometxt.appendChild(allDoneEl);
    // Create a form
    const f = document.createElement("form"); 
    // Add it to the document body
    document.body.appendChild(f); 
    

           
    
}
```

What I am trying to do is following the results page showing "your score is "
I need a form element for the users to enter their initials and submit.

Comment: You should probably do some more research on how forms work. A form is useless without any form controls for user to enter anything and then submit the form

Comment: A good place to start is to check out the examples from the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/append/) and see if you can get a working prototype.

Answer (score 1):

```
 // create a form for accepting the initial
    var inputForm = document.createElement("form");
    inputForm.setAttribute("id", "inputForm");

    //Add an input element to form
    var inputText = document.createElement("input");
    inputText.setAttribute("type", "text");
    inputText.setAttribute("id", "initialstext");
    inputText.setAttribute("placeholder", "Enter your initials");
    inputForm.appendChild(inputText);

    // Add it to the document body
    scoresSection.appendChild(inputForm);
    // create a button for submitting the form
    var submitBtn = document.createElement("button");
    submitBtn.setAttribute("id", "submitBtn");
    submitBtn.setAttribute("style", "float: center; position: relative;");
    submitBtn.innerHTML = "Submit";
    scoresSection.appendChild(submitBtn);
```

I tried this and it worked. Thank you @MrCano369

Answer (score 0):

```
const f = document.createElement("form");

//Add an input element to form
const input = document.createElement("input");
f.appendChild(input);

// Add it to the document body
document.body.appendChild(f);
```